# invisible redirect using htaccess + pushstate, issues

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, pushstate

I have been starting to dive into using pushstate to drive my single page web application and ran into a problem with my .htaccess

I initially want to redirect all url calls to the root folder of the website, but keep the old url in the address bar for jquery to use and load with pushstate.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+)$ /$1 [L]
```

This is my redirect, but the problem the when jquery tries to get the dynamic content, it spits out a 500 error. Also, when I navigate to any sub-directory, the browser also spits out a 500 error.

+my site is on a sub-domain.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

EDIT:

thank you for the response @anubhava.

I tried this "RewriteRule ^ / [L,R]" with no luck. I even added "[L,R=301]" to it.

Is it significant to say that this is a sub-domain that I am working on? eg: sub.domain.com

I have done this on a non sub domain site with the following and had no issue:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|png)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ / [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404/
```

Thank you all for responses. I'm new to this stuff and managed to understand that, you can indeed reroute any sort of request to the /root directory. BUT, if the request is to a folder the already exists, the re-route wont work. Unless you remove the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` line.

But removing that line also disallows your app to send or receive ajax calls too. The response you get is your index.php instead.

I did the url rerouting within my app to look for urls with specific key words and loaded the matching content from another folder.

**** The line with the 404 redirects someone to my /404/ which the app also handles

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to redirect to the root, your rule is not quite right. Try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ / [L]
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I have already tried this technique, as it works fine. The only thing is that, if you refresh the page with the url changed, the browser does not load the root.

Example:

instead of domain.com/locations redirecting to domain.com (with "/locations" still visible to the user), it opens up "/locations" instead.

I hope this makes sense

Comment: +1 it should work. @bheku: Try adding `R` flag in e.g. `RewriteRule ^ / [L,R]`

Comment: thank you for the response @anubhava. 

I tried this RewriteRule ^ / [L,R] with no luck. I even added "[L,R=301]" to it.

Is it significant to say that this is a sub-domain that I am working on? eg: sub.domain.com

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^ / [L]` with 2 `RewriteCond` lines

Comment: Are you saying that you also want to change the domain? Go from sub.domain to domain?

Comment: thank you for your comments. I managed to utilize the - RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?url=$1 [L,QSA] - and it does route back to the root, but i am curious about the - RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d - As I understand, this makes sure existing directories are ignored in the rewrite rules. But this is an issue, because I want existing folders  to also be directed to the root. So I took the lines off and ran into a new problem. My ajax calls in the app are also in a way blocked. any suggestions? thanks